# Add prefix NS0 only in the root node

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, transformation, prefix

Hy Guys,

Please, help me! I need include the namespace prefix only in the first node of XML, the other nodes must be without prefix and namespace. See the example below.

Before:

```
<RootNode xmlns="https://xxx/yyy/v1">
<CreatedBy>admin</CreatedBy>
<Task>
<Number>1</Number>
<Status>-1</Status>
<Name>Fechada</Name>
</Task>
</RootNode>
```

After:

```
<ns0:RootNode xmlns:ns0="https://xxx/yyy/v1">
<CreatedBy>admin</CreatedBy>
<Task>
<Number>1</Number>
<Status>-1</Status>
<Name>Fechada</Name>
</Task>
</ns0:RootNode>
```

How can I do this using XSL?

Comment: Can you confirm this is exactly what you want to do this? In the first XML, all elements are in the namespace "https://xxx/yyy/v1", but in the second XML, only the RootNode would be in that namespace, and all other elements are in no namespace, so the two XML documents are not equivalent. Thanks!

Comment: Hy Tim! It's the problem, The root and another elements aren't in the same namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two things you want to do here.

1) Add a namespace prefix to the root element. This can be done with the following template

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:element name="ns0:{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

2) For all other elements, create elements with the same name but in no namespace. This can be done with the following

```
  <xsl:template match="*/*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

Putting this all together, with the identity template to handle everything else, gives you the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:element name="ns0:{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*/*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```